# Recursion in Javascript not working (CodeWars questions)

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I've been working on a Codewars question for a minute now. Im pretty much done with it if I could get this recursion working in my function. It supposed to be a depth first search, but after failing for the first time the recursive calls do not execute. I will point out the problem area.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/path-finder-number-1-can-you-reach-the-exit/train/javascript

```
function pathFinder(maze) {
    maze = maze.split('').filter(e => e !== '\n').join('');
    let length = Math.sqrt(maze.length);
    console.log('length', length);
    let map = maze.split('');
    let checked = new Array(maze.length);
    checked.fill(false);
    let won = [];
    helper(0, length, map, checked, won);
    return won.length > 0;
}

function helper(pos, length, map, checked, won) {
    console.log(pos);
    if (pos == map.length - 1) {
        won.push(true);
    }
    checked[pos] = true;
    let up = down = left = right = false;
    up = checkUp(pos, length, map, checked);
    down = checkDown(pos, length, map, checked);
    left = checkLeft(pos, length, map, checked);
    right = checkRight(pos, length, map, checked);
    console.log("U",up,"D",down,"L",left,"R",right);
***************
AT THE FOLLOWING IF STATEMENT, ONCE THE FIRST IF STATEMENT IS TRUE, 

THE OTHER ONES DO NOT GET EXECUTED(ex if Up = true, and Down = true,

only Up will get executed)
***************
    if (up) {
        console.log("U")
        helper(pos += length, length, map, checked, won);
    }
    if (down) {
       console.log("D")
       helper(pos -= length, length, map, checked, won);
    }
    if (left) {
        console.log("L")
        helper(pos -= 1, length, map, checked, won);
    }
    if (right) {
        console.log("R")
        helper(pos += 1, length, map, checked, won);
    }
}

function checkRow(prev, next, length) {
    return Math.floor(prev / length) - Math.floor(next / length);
}

function checkUp(prev, length, arr, checked) {
    let next = prev + length;
    return (arr.length && (checkRow(prev, next, length) == -1) && arr[next] == '.' && !checked[next]);
}

function checkDown(prev, length, arr, checked) {
    let next = prev - length;
    return (next >= 0 && (checkRow(prev, next, length) == 1) && arr[next] == '.' && !checked[next]);
}

function checkLeft(prev, length, arr, checked) {
    let next = prev - 1;
    return (next >= 0 && (checkRow(prev, next, length) == 0) && arr[next] == '.' && !checked[next]);
}

function checkRight(prev, length, arr, checked) {
    let next = prev + 1;
    return (next <= arr.length && (checkRow(prev, next, length) == 0) && arr[next] == '.' && !checked[next]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `down` doesn't gets executed at some point? Since you call `helper` again in that if statement (`if (up)`), you'll actually do all the checks and then reach the region with 4 if statements again. If `up` is true again, you'll call the function one more time and so on. There's no logical explanation `if (down)` wouldn't be executed if `down` is 100% `true`.

Comment: yes I am sure because I put console log statements and only the first true "if" was getting put onto the console

Comment: What if you put a `console.log("down")` right inside the if block, before calling helper? Can you add a small input and the desired output? We can't really help you if we don't know what you expect to receive (or if we don't know the initial problem statement).

Comment: pathFinder(".........W....WW..W.W.WW...W.W.W....");

this is supposed to be true. I'LL edit code to reflect console statements I had before

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/path-finder-number-1-can-you-reach-the-exit/train/javascript

Comment: you *do* realize that writing `let won = [];` in one function and then using `won` in another means that a) you use a uninitialized variable and b) the `won` in the first function is a different `won`?

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean. i thought that if i pass the same object reference to every recursive stack, each stack would have the same object reference. thus it acts as kind of a global variable to signal when a path is found

Comment: im using "won" two times but in different scopes?

Comment: sorry, I missed that. One is okay. But `down, left, right` are in global scope. this is maybe your problem?

Comment: i thought i was using shorthand to initialize multiple variables. after changing initializing all variables separately one of the test i passed fails, so you may be on to something. ill see if it leads to something right now..

Comment: shorthand would be `let up = false, down = false, ...`. You have global `down` and so if in your recursion you set it false its still false when you end the recursive step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that this:

```
let up = down = left = right = false;
```

only initializes one variable : `up`.

Just switching to strict mode with a `"use strict";` at the beginning of the file reveales the problem:

> let up = down = left = right = false;
>                                   ^
>
> ReferenceError: right is not defined